# _.unshift/_,push() is not a function, whenever I'm chaining. What's the logic behind this?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit familiar with chaining methods, but when I try to chain unshift and push together, I get an error message saying _.unshift/.push is not a function, although, If I use both methods consecutively, there's no issue whatsoever. I just want to know the logic behind this.

The code below works just fine.

```
function mixedNumbers(arr) {
   arr.unshift('I', 2, 'three')
   arr.push(7, 'VIII', 9)
   return arr;
}

console.log(mixedNumbers(['IV', 5, 'six']));
```

Whereas, the code below this, doesn't.

```
function mixedNumbers(arr) {
   arr.unshift('I', 2, 'three').push(7, 'VIII', 9);
   return arr;
}

console.log(mixedNumbers(['IV', 5, 'six']));
```

Why is that? (Bare in mind I'm a newbie, so please try to keep explanations from being too complex)

Comment: *"The `unshift()` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and **returns the new length of the array**"*

Comment: So unshift can't be chained?

Comment: Chaining is allowed when each method returns the instance on which it was called. In the case of array methods like `unshift`, they don't return the array instance, so you can't chain methods.

Comment: It returns 6. So, it becomes `6.push(7, 'VIII', 9)`. You can create a new array in one line: `return ['I', 2, 'three', ...arr, 7, 'VIII', 9]`. But, to mutate `arr`, you need to do in 2 lines

Comment: Ah, I get that. So is that logic the same for push, pop and unshift?

Comment: Please check the documentation for all those. `pop` and `shift` returns the removed element, `splice` returns the removed elements as array, `push` and `unshift` return the new length of the array

Comment: I know what they do, I'm asking if following the same logic, those 3 methods, also would not be able to be chained? Just like unshift. I know push wouldn't

Comment: Chaining is not a special concept. It's calling a method on whatever is returned by the previous method. You can do `arr.concat(1).concat(2).concat(3)` because `concat` returns a brand new array and arrays have a `concat` method on them. `arr.push(1)` returns a number. So, you can do `arr.push(1).toFixed(2)` because toFixed is a method that can be called on numbers

Comment: You can do `return ['I', 2, 'three'].concat(arr).concat(7, 'VIII', 9)` or `return ['I', 2, 'three', ...arr, 7, 'VIII', 9]`. They will not update `arr`. They create new arrays.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thanks, Adiga